# Issue while sharing title in outlook app on ios device in react native

Tags: react-native, outlook, share

I'm using

```
import { Share } from 'react-native'; 

Share.share(
      {
        title: title,
        message: text,
      },
      {
        // iOS only:
        excludedActivityTypes: [],
        subject: title
      },
    );
```

I need to share title and body. This code snippet working fine in Android (on Gmail, Outlook and Yahoo).

But when comes to iOS, the title is not added (Working fine in mail app and Gmail).

Is it a limitation with npm package/outlook or is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with outlook. At the moment I don't have a workaround either.